# Solve definite integral of infinite series of a complex function

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

I need to calculate the following integral.
$$\int _{\frac{-2 \pi}{L}}^{\frac{2\pi}{L}} \left( \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(j \chi \rho \cos\left(\xi - \theta\right) \right)^n}{n!}\right) d\xi$$

where $j$ is the imaginary unit, $\chi \geq 0, \chi \in \Bbb R$, $\rho \in \Bbb R$, $\theta \in \Bbb R$ and $L>0 \in \Bbb N$.

Is there a theorem as of how to move the infinite series out of the integral? Or a solution for this kind of integral?

Comment: Try to place parentheses : you will see that there is a problem with the differential element that, IMHO, shouldn't be $d\xi_i$... Otherwise your question about exchanging the sum and integral signs is already solved..

Comment: Hi Jean Marie . I placed parentheses around the quantity I need to integrate.

Comment: Therefore, don't you see that your $d \xi_i$ is "floating in the air"...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Jean Marie. The $i$ index was irrellevant. The $\chi_i$ and $\xi_i$ parameters did not corespond to indexed parameters.

Comment: Your series surely comes from the expansion of a (complex) exponential.... Could you say why you haven't attempted to obtain the result through a (more or less classical) integration method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Riemann integral, we know that if $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(j \chi \rho cos\left(\xi - \theta\right) \right)^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $\xi \in [\frac{-2 \pi}{L},\frac{2\pi}{L}]$ as $n \to \infty$, then we can move the sum outside the integral.  Try the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) to prove uniform convergence.

The Lebesgue theory of integration provides additional criteria that allow moving the sum outside the integral.  See, for example, the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) .

---

**added**
Note that
$$
\left|\frac{\big(j\chi\rho\cos(\xi-\theta)\big)^n}{n!}\right|
\le\frac{\big(\chi|\rho|\big)^n}{n!} ,
$$
and the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\big(\chi|\rho|\big)^n}{n!}
$$
converges [to $e^{\chi|\rho|}$].  Therefore, by the Weierstrass $M$-test,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\big(j\chi\rho\cos(\xi-\theta)\big)^n}{n!}
$$
converges uniformly for $\xi \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks GEdgar for your answer. If I performed the Weirstrass stress correctly I see that the inner function does not converge. Hence I cannot change the order of summation and integration. Is there any other alternative to solve this kind of integral?